# How to add contacts to customer

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav

I try to add contacts to a customer, like this:

```
   WHILE (LoopCount <> 0) DO
   BEGIN
       KlantContact.GET(FirstContact);
       KlantContact.VALIDATE(KlantContact."Company No.", BussinesContactName."Contact No.");     //'44241';
       KlantContact.MODIFY;
       MESSAGE(KlantContact.Name);
       LoopCount := LoopCount - 1;
       FirstContact := INCSTR(FirstContact);    
   END;
```

But the problem is that the contacts are not connected with the customer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the Contact Business Relation table to link them together. Just check the table structure.

Otherwise, if you set up the Bus. Relation Codes in the Marketing Setup NAV will create a new Contact in the background for Customers, Vendors and Bank Accounts.

Comment: At azatoth. Thank you. Solved

Answer (score 2):

If you look in the `OnInsert` trigger of the Customer Table you can see, that a Method `UpdateContFromCust.OnInsert(Rec);` is called. Within this Method a new Contact Bus. Relation is inserted.

From Method InsertNewContact (Codeunit 5056), with `Cont` beeing the contact and `RMSetup` beeing `Marketing Setup`

```
 WITH ContBusRel DO BEGIN
      INIT;
      "Contact No." := Cont."No.";
      "Business Relation Code" := RMSetup."Bus. Rel. Code for Customers";
      "Link to Table" := "Link to Table"::Customer;
      "No." := Cust."No.";
      INSERT(TRUE);
    END;
```

Comment: At Campl3r. Thank you for your answare. I have solved now